# Lazy loading ignoring Explicit Loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I have a entity loaded with explicit loading but when i try access the loaded references it is loaded again with **lazy loading** without where clausule!

The only way i found is disable Lazy Loading which i can't!

I don't understand why it's loading again if i already explicit loaded the references.

> Here's a example (i shorted a little bit for demonstration
>   purposes):

```
        var employee = dbo.Employees
            .Where(m => m.StoreId == SessionContext.Store
                && m.Id == 10)
            .Include(m => m.Person)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (employee == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        dbo.Entry(employee)
            .Collection(m => m.Stocks)
            .Query()
            .Where(m => ...)
            .Load();

        // LAZY LOADING HERE
        foreach (var stock in employee.Stocks)
        {
        }
```

Comment: did you added the code to disable lazy loading `dbo.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            dbo.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;`

Comment: Like i said yes! But i need understand why it is loading again if is already loaded, explicit! Thanks anyway!

Comment: When we have lazy loading disabled and still need to lazy load items We usually tend to use the Load method on the related entity’s entry. So in your case its lazy loading so it will not load until its evaluated .

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx

Comment: I think that when you're iterating employee.Stocks you are not iterating the stocks filtered on you conditional Load query, you are iterating ALL the stocks, that's why lazy loading gets triggered

Comment: First you need make sure you are not inadvertently lazy loading anything you don't want to by killing the context before iterating by wrapping the context in a Using code block

Comment: @Eldho if you look at the end of this page you will see they loading related entites as well! See the load method documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.load(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Load(System.Linq.IQueryable)

Comment: why not just write : `var employeeStocksFiltered = dbo.Entry(employee)
            .Collection(m => m.Stocks)
            .Query()
            .Where(m => ...)
            .ToList();
foreach (var stock in employeeStocksFiltered )
        {
        }` ?

Comment: I was wrong , let me research and update you

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable Lazy Load, EF will try to fetch all stocks when you iterate them

Wrap your context with a Using block

```
using(DbContext dbo=new DbContext())
{
   //Disable lazy loading
   dbo.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled=false;
   var employee = GetEmployee()...


   dbo.Entry(employee)
        .Collection(m => m.Stocks)
        .Query()
        .Where(m => ...)
        .Load();

}//Kill the context

    // NO LAZY LOADING HERE
    foreach (var stock in employee.Stocks)//If you don't disable Lazy Loading, EF will try to fetch all stocks
    {
    }
```

*When using the Query method it is usually best to turn off lazy loading for the navigation property. This is because otherwise the entire collection may get loaded automatically by the lazy loading mechanism either before or **after** the filtered query has been executed.*

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Otherwise, if you don't want to disable Lazy Loading, you'll have to do what jbl says

```
var employeeStocksFiltered = dbo.Entry(employee) .Collection(m => m.Stocks) .Query() .Where(m => ...) .ToList(); 
foreach (var stock in employeeStocksFiltered ) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

To work properly, `Include()` should appear right after the `DbSet` object:

```
var employee = dbo.Employees
        .Include(m => m.Person)
        .Include(m => m.Stocks)
        .Where(m => m.Stocks....)
        .FirstOrDefault(m => m.StoreId == SessionContext.Store
            && m.Id == 10);
```